# FutureProvider emits state with old value after invalidation, causing Dismissible widget errors

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Here's an example of a very simple app showing a list of sorted items. Items come from Riverpod's providers.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:pillarium/utils/logger.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'main.g.dart';

@riverpod
class ListState extends _$ListState {
  @override
  Future<List<int>> build() {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => List.generate(
        10,
        (index) => index,
      ),
    );
  }

  void remove(int id) {
    final items = state.requireValue;
    items.remove(id);
    state = AsyncData(items);
  }
}

@riverpod
Future<List<String>> sortedList(SortedListRef ref) async {
  final list = await ref.watch(listStateProvider.future);
  return list.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
}

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Consumer(
          builder: (context, ref, child) {
            final itemList = ref.watch(sortedListProvider);
            logger.d("itemList: $itemList");
            return itemList.maybeWhen(
              skipLoadingOnReload: true,
              data: (data) => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: ValueKey(data[index]),
                    onDismissed: (direction) =>
                        ref.read(listStateProvider.notifier).remove(index),
                    background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(data[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              orElse: () => const SizedBox.shrink(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when I delete an item, the `sortedListProvider` emits `AsyncLoading` state with *old* item list. Here's the output log after I deleted the item '3':

```
itemList: AsyncLoading<List<String>>(value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
itemList: AsyncData<List<String>>(value: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I understand that it's because of the nature of FutureProvider: the `sortedListProvider` gets invalidated once the `listStateProvider` emits a new state. Is there a way to make it emitting the updated list of items? The current setup gives me this error:

```
A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from
the application once that handler has fired.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Dismissible-[<'3'>]
```